# searching NSString from NSMutableArray and Adding in UiTableView

Tags: ios, string, search, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

i have contains list of countries. such as

```
countries_list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Afghanistan",@"Albania",
@"Bolivia",@"Bulgaria",@"China", @"Estonia",@"France",@"Finland",
@"Greenland",@"Iceland",@"Japan", nil];
```

from this array i need to search such as Albania in sorted list all countries come which start with the alphabet Letter A and then sort Al so on and then i have to add these values in the uitableview..
i just need searching  help me if any one can. thanks

```
 NSMutableArray* containsAnother = [NSMutableArray array];
 NSMutableArray* doesntAnother = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString* item in inputArray)
{
    if ([item rangeOfString:@"Finland"].location != NSNotFound){
        [containsAnother addObject:item];

    NSLog(@"country is found..%@",containsAnother);

    }else{


    }
        [doesntContainAnother addObject:item];
   NSLog(@"country is not found..%@",doesntContainAnother);

}



NSLog(@"array is found..%@",containsAnother);
```

Comment: What type of searching are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

try using `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:` method

```
 countries_list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Afghanistan",@"Albania",@"Bolivia",@"Bulgaria",@"China", @"Estonia",@"France",@"Finland", @"Greenland",@"Iceland",@"Japan", nil];

 NSPredicate *predicte = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"Self beginswith[c] %@", @"Albania"];
 NSArray *filteredArray = [countries_list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicte];    
 NSLog([filteredArray description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate class for this like this :-

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];

// Loop to fetch Team Names and store in NSMutableArray named array
for (NSDictionary *data in mySortedArray) {
    NSString *TEAMNAME = @"TeamName";
    NSString *countryName = @"Australia";    

NSDictionary sortDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:countryName,TEAMNAME,nil];
[array addObject:sortDictionary];
}

NSSortDescriptor * ratingDescriptor =[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:TEAMNAME ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ratingDescriptor, nil];
mySortedArray = (NSMutableArray *)[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

And it is done. Hope it helps :)